# regexp extract with lookbehind and lookforward with google-re2 in google data studio

Tags: regex, looker-studio, re2

I'm trying to build a `REGEXP_EXTRACT` query inside a `CASE` statement which isn't quite working out the way I want to:

**Example data:**

```
1234-ABC
1234-abc
1234-ABC-1a
1234
1234-abc-test-this
```

What I would like to to is catch the `ABC|abc` out of the query if present. If it's not present I would like to return a default value.

I found a page where I can see the regex possibilities for [Google-RE2 RegEx](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax).

I know how to build the case:

```
CASE
    WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Eventcategory, '^([0-9])*-([a-zA-Z0-9])*$') THEN 'it matches 1234-ABC and 1234-abc'
    WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Eventcategory, '^([0-9])*-([a-zA-Z0-9])*-([a-zA-Z0-9])*') THEN 'it matches 1234-ABC-1a and 1234-abc-test-this'
    ELSE "it matches 1234"
END
```

The problem comes in extracting the right part of `Eventcategory`.

What I've tried so far:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Eventcategory, '-([a-zA-Z0-9])*-') // Then it was only still needed to remove the - at the beginning and end
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Eventcategory, '-([a-zA-Z0-9])*$') // if it was 1234-Abc
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Eventcategory, '(?=^([0-9])*-)((-[a-zA-Z])*)')
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Eventcategory, '((-[a-zA-Z])*)')
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Eventcategory, '(?=^([0-9])*-)((-[a-zA-Z])*)')
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Eventcategory, '(-([a-zA-Z])+)')
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Eventcategory, '(?=(^([0-9])*-))(-([a-zA-Z])+)')
```

Really hope someone can help me out since I don't have any options left at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make your pattern work, you need to use  a single capturing group around the pattern part you need to extract, put the `*` after the character class and remove the `$` anchor:

```
'^[0-9]*-([a-zA-Z0-9]*)'
```

Or, you may also make sure you match at least 1 char of each subpattern by replacing `*` (0 or more) with `+` (1 or more):

```
'^[0-9]+-([a-zA-Z0-9]+)'
```

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pp0d5v/2).

Alternatively, you may use

```
^[^-]+-([^-]+)
```

It will match

- `^` - start of string
- `[^-]+` - 1 or more chars other than `-`
- `-` - a hyphen
- `([^-]+)` - Group 1 (your extracted value): 1+ chars other than `-`

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pp0d5v/1).